# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended Error at Line: 3 Column: 35

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a script that creates a TABLE and I have problem with the last command which I have to do:

> ```
> SELECT Studenci.Nazwisko,
>    Trunc(Months_Between(Sysdate,Studenci.RokUrodzenia)/12) Wiek FROM
>    Studenci.RokUrodzenia to_date('1980','YYYY')
> ```

This is my script; what am I doing wrong?

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE Studenci(
>        NrIndeksu NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
>        Nazwisko VARCHAR2(16),
>        RokUrodzenia NUMBER(4),
>        Kierunek VARCHAR2(12)
>     );
>
>     CREATE TABLE Wykladowcy(
>        IdWykladowcy NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
>        Nazwisko VARCHAR2(16),
>        Stopien VARCHAR2(6),
>        Stanowisko VARCHAR(8)
>     );
>
>     CREATE TABLE Kursy(
>        IdKursu NUMBER(1) PRIMARY KEY,
>        Nazwa VARCHAR2(18),
>        IdWykladowcy NUMBER(4) REFERENCES Wykladowcy
>     );
>
>     CREATE TABLE Rejstracje(
>        NrIndeksu NUMBER(3) REFERENCES Studenci , 
>        IdKursu NUMBER(1)  REFERENCES Kursy ,
>        Data DATE
>     );
>
>
>     CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Ind_Kursy_naz ON Kursy(Nazwa);
>     CREATE INDEX Ind_Studenci_naz ON Studenci(Nazwisko);
>     CREATE INDEX Ind_Wykladowcy_naz ON Wykladowcy(Nazwisko);
>
>     INSERT INTO Wykladowcy VALUES (1010,'Kowalski Jan', 'Dr', 'Adiunkt');
>     INSERT INTO Wykladowcy VALUES (1011,'Jakubowski Emil','Dr hab','Docent');
>     INSERT INTO Wykladowcy VALUES (1012,'Gazda Mirosław','Dr','Profesor');
>
>     INSERT INTO Kursy VALUES (1,'Bazy danych',1010);
>     INSERT INTO Kursy VALUES (2,'Systemy operacyjne',1012);
>     INSERT INTO Kursy VALUES (3,'Multimedia',1011);
>     INSERT INTO Kursy VALUES (4,'Sieci komputerowe',null);
>
>     INSERT INTO Studenci VALUES (101,'Kuczyńska Ewa',1980,'Bazy danych');
>     INSERT INTO Studenci VALUES (102,'Lubicz Robert',1985,'Multimedia');
>     INSERT INTO Studenci VALUES (103,'Krajewski Bogdan',1988,'Bazy danych');
>     INSERT INTO Studenci VALUES (104,'Lityńska Anna',1987,'Multimedia');
>     INSERT INTO Studenci VALUES (105,'Marzec Marcin',1982,'Multimedia');
>     INSERT INTO Studenci VALUES (106,'Cichaocki Rafał',1989,'Bazy danych');
>
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (101,1,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (102,3,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (104,3,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (106,1,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (104,2,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (101,4,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (103,1,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (103,1,NULL);
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje VALUES (105,1,NULL);
>
>
>     UPDATE Rejstracje SET Rejstracje.IdKursu=Rejstracje.IdKursu*3
>     WHERE Rejstracje.NrIndeksu=105;
>     COMMIT UPDATE
>
>     INSERT INTO Rejstracje(Data)
>     VALUES (Sysdate);
>
>     SELECT *FROM Kursy
>     WHERE Kursy.IdWykladowcy IS NULL;
>
>     SELECT *FROM Rejstracje
>     WHERE Rejstracje.NrIndeksu=101;
>
>     SELECT Kursy.Nazwa 
>     FROM Kursy
>     ORDER BY Nazwa ASC;
>
>     SELECT Studenci.Nazwisko,
>     Trunc(Months_Between(Sysdate,Studenci.RokUrodzenia)/12) Wiek
>     FROM Studenci.RokUrodzenia to_date('1980','YYYY')
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems like a missing `;`.

Comment: It might be just a missing semi-colon; fixing that would only be the start of resolving the problems with the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL:

```
SELECT Studenci.Nazwisko,
       Trunc(Months_Between(Sysdate,Studenci.RokUrodzenia)/12) Wiek
  FROM Studenci.RokUrodzenia to_date('1980','YYYY');
```

is invalid because the `to_date()` call can't go there like that.

You are probably looking for something like:

```
SELECT Studenci.Nazwisko,
       Trunc(Months_Between(Sysdate,Studenci.RokUrodzenia)/12) Wiek
  FROM Studenci
 WHERE RokUrodzenia = 1980;
```

given that `RokUrodenzia` is a NUMBER(4) column and not a DATE column.  You may still have to do some work to get the MONTHS_BETWEEN() call to work since RokUrodenzia is not a DATE (as I said) and MONTHS_BETWEEN probably expects a date.  You'll have to investigate how to fix that; you might use TO_DATE() there legitimately.

Comment: Its not working, but when i change RokUrodzenia for DATE column, its say me i can't insert Values in format 1980. I'm new in SQL i started study it 1 week ago, and really need help

Comment: Is RokUrodzenia a date of birth, so you're trying to select the students name and age? If so, why not insert the YYYY-mm-dd part of an Oracle DATE into a DATE column. Then you can do MONTHS_BETWEEN with ease. If you only want year of birth, then you may do best without MONTHS_BETWEEN, and simply convert the year portion of SYSDATE to a number. I don't work with Oracle as a primary DBMS, and date/time handling is always the most eccentric part of every SQL DBMS.  You can probably use TO_NUMBER() as part of the answer; you may need TO_CHAR() too: `TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))`?